# Spark streaming performance tuning

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a `spark-streaming` job in Python, and it reads directly from Kafka via `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` and then processes the data via  `reduceByKeyAndWindow`([see here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams)).

However, I'm now experiencing a strange issue, the job runs with a `1min` window setting, but sometimes the data processing time takes `10min`, and I spotted that, each time this kind of strange issue occurs, looks like one single task takes way too long time than the other tasks, please see the figures below.

There 516 tasks, and 515 of them have finished, 1 lags behind.

[image]

If I follow the description link and dig in further, here is what I find (see below), looks like there're multiple stages, and all previous stages finished very quickly (duration less than 1s), but the last stage with **36** task, 35 of them finished but **1 lags behind**.

[image]

Any idea why this issue occurs?

Comment: How to create a [mcve]. _I spotted that, each time this kind of strange issue occurs, looks like one single task takes way too long time_ - almost always indicates data skew, either in the source (Kafka partition) or during aggregations.

Comment: It might be due to the fact that one of your keys is more represented than the other ones or is NULL

Comment: @zero323, ok, but how to deal with this skewness issue then?

Comment: @Marie, how to debug this issue to find out if it's really a data-skew issue? and then how to fix it?

Comment: Try counting the number of keys, especially NULLs. If this is not the issue try increasing the number of tasks using argument `numTasks` in `reduceByKeyAndWindow`

Comment: @Marie, it doesn't looks like data skewness, because each time this long delay occurs, it takes `10min`, no more no less, if it's data skewness issue, how could it be?

Answer (score 0):

**Try below change in your processing** :

After reading Data through KafkaUtils.createDirectStream, repartition your data and then apply any transformations.

```
   option-1 : repartition(10) 
   option-2 : repartition(20)
```

Set below spark property to avoid generating many intermediate files :

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 10)
```